# CLI with Picocli: Call main command before sub command get called

Tags: java, command-line-interface, picocli

I switched from Apache Commons CLI to Picocli because of the sub command support (and annotation-based declaration).

Consider a command line tool like `git`, with sub commands like `push`. Git have a main switch `--verbose` or `-v` for enable verbose mode in **all** sub commands.
How can I implement a main switch that is executed **before** any sub commands?

This is my test

```
@CommandLine.Command(name = "push",
        description = "Update remote refs along with associated objects")
class PushCommand implements Callable<Void> {
    @Override
    public Void call() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("#PushCommand.call");

        return null;
    }
}

@CommandLine.Command(description = "Version control", subcommands = {PushCommand.class})
public class GitApp implements Callable<Void> {
    @CommandLine.Option(names = {"-h", "--help"}, usageHelp = true, description = "Display this help message.")
    private boolean usageHelpRequested;

    @CommandLine.Option(names = {"-v", "--verbose"}, description = "Verbose mode. Helpful for troubleshooting.")
    private boolean verboseMode;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GitApp app = new GitApp();
        CommandLine.call(app, "--verbose", "push");
        System.out.println("#GitApp.main after. verbose: " + (app.verboseMode));
    }

    @Override
    public Void call() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("#GitApp.call");

        return null;
    }
}
```

Output is

```
#PushCommand.call
#GitApp.main after. verbose: true
```

I would expect, that `GitApp.call` get called before the sub command get called. But only the sub command get called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `CommandLine.call` (and `CommandLine.run`) methods only invoke the [*last* subcommand](http://picocli.info/#_less_boilerplate) by design, so what you are seeing in the original post is the expected behaviour.

The `call` and `run` methods are actually a shortcut. The following two lines are equivalent:

```
CommandLine.run(callable, args); // internally uses RunLast, equivalent to: 
new CommandLine(callable).parseWithHandler(new RunLast(), args);
```

> Update: from picocli 4.0, the above methods are deprecated, and replaced with `new CommandLine(myapp).execute(args)`. The "handler" is now called the "execution strategy" (example below).

There is also a [`RunAll` handler](http://picocli.info/#_convenience_methods_for_subcommands) that runs *all* commands that were matched. The following `main` method gives the desired behaviour:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    args = new String[] { "--verbose", "push" };
    GitApp app = new GitApp();
    // before picocli 4.0:
    new CommandLine(app).parseWithHandler(new RunAll(), args);
    // from picocli 4.0:
    //new CommandLine(app).setExecutionStrategy(new RunAll()).execute(args);
    System.out.println("#GitApp.main after. verbose: " + (app.verboseMode));
}
```

Output:

```
#GitApp.call
#PushCommand.call
#GitApp.main after. verbose: true
```

You may also be interested in the [`@ParentCommand`](http://picocli.info/#__code_parentcommand_code_annotation) annotation. This tells picocli to inject an instance of the parent command into a subcommand. Your subcommand can then call methods on the parent command, for example to check whether `verbose` is true. For example:

> Update: from picocli 4.0, use the `setExecutionStrategy` method to specify `RunAll`. The below example is updated to use the new picocli 4.0+ API.

```
import picocli.CommandLine;
import picocli.CommandLine.*;

@Command(name = "push",
        description = "Update remote refs along with associated objects")
class PushCommand implements Runnable {

    @ParentCommand // picocli injects the parent instance
    private GitApp parentCommand;

    public void run() {
        System.out.printf("#PushCommand.call: parent.verbose=%s%n",
                parentCommand.verboseMode); // use parent instance
    }
}

@Command(description = "Version control",
        mixinStandardHelpOptions = true, // auto-include --help and --version
        subcommands = {PushCommand.class,
                       HelpCommand.class}) // built-in help subcommand
public class GitApp implements Runnable {
    @Option(names = {"-v", "--verbose"},
            description = "Verbose mode. Helpful for troubleshooting.")
    boolean verboseMode;

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("#GitApp.call");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        args = new String[] { "--verbose", "push" };

        GitApp app = new GitApp();
        int exitCode = new CommandLine(app)
            .setExecutionStrategy(new RunAll())
            .execute(args);

        System.out.println("#GitApp.main after. verbose: " + (app.verboseMode));
        System.exit(exitCode);
    }
}
```

Other minor edits: made the annotations a bit more compact by importing the inner classes. You may also like the [`mixinStandardHelpOptions`](http://picocli.info/#_mixin_standard_help_options) attribute and the built-in [`help`](http://picocli.info/#_built_in_help_subcommand) subcommand that help reduce boilerplate code.

Comment: Great tips! Thank you for Picocli as well!

Answer (score 0):

As Picocli supports inheritance with Options I've extracted the `--help` and `--verbose` Option into an abstract class `BaseCommand` and invoke `super.call` from the subcommands.

```
abstract class BaseCommand implements Callable<Void> {
    @CommandLine.Option(names = {"-h", "--help"}, usageHelp = true, description = "Display this help message.")
    private boolean usageHelpRequested;

    @CommandLine.Option(names = {"-v", "--verbose"}, description = "Verbose mode. Helpful for troubleshooting.")
    private boolean verboseMode;

    @Override
    public Void call() throws Exception {
        if (verboseMode) {
            setVerbose();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void setVerbose() {
        System.out.println("enter verbose mode");
    }
}

@CommandLine.Command(name = "push",
        description = "Update remote refs along with associated objects")
class PushCommand extends BaseCommand {
    @Override
    public Void call() throws Exception {
        super.call();
        System.out.println("Execute push command");
        return null;
    }
}

@CommandLine.Command(description = "Version control", subcommands = {PushCommand.class})
public class GitApp extends BaseCommand {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GitApp app = new GitApp();
        CommandLine.call(app, "push", "--verbose");
    }

    @Override
    public Void call() throws Exception {
        super.call();
        System.out.println("GitApp.call called");
        return null;
    }
}
```